# Android simulator running Expo (React-Native) not showing the new code (doesn´t update)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using the expo-cli tool to develop in react native. I am using an android simulator: Once i run "yarn start" the console asks me:

```
To run the app with live reloading, choose one of:
  • Scan the QR code above with the Expo app (Android) or the Camera app (iOS).
  • Press a for Android emulator.
  • Press e to send a link to your phone with email.
  • Press s to sign in and enable more options.
```

I press a. The simulator loads the expo app succesfully but the text displayed is not updated. What i mean with this is that before I just had this on app.js:

```
    export default function App() {
  return (
    <UtilityThemeProvider>
      <Box><Text>Hello App</Text></Box>
    </UtilityThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

And indeed it was showing `Hello App`. But then I installed react navigation and similar dependiencies and i have this on app.js:

```
   export default function App() {
  return (
    <UtilityThemeProvider>
      <Navigation />
    </UtilityThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

There is no error showing. Not in the console of the simulator, nor in the console, nor in the metro bundler! But the android simulator still it´s showing `Hello App`

Here´s how i export and import the `Navigator` component:

**index.js:**

```js
export default class Navigation extends Component{
    state = {}
    render(){
        return <AppNavigator />
    }
}
```

**App.js:**

```
import Navigation from './src/views/index'
```

Things i´ve tried:

1. Restart the simulator device 
   2- Stop the server and run `yarn start` again 
   3- Make sure my IDE is still in autosave mode

Any idea what i could do? Could it be possible that i´ve touched something to disable re-load?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Android simulator Ctrl + M and check if you have Enable Live Reload option